# JavaScript onclick event handlers not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

For some reason, my `onclick` JavaScript event handlers are not functioning properly.

Here is my markup, script and style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Quadratic Root Finder</title>

<script>
document.ready = function() {
    document.getElementById('calculate').onClick.calculateQuad()
    {
        var inputa = document.getElementById('variablea').value;
        var inputb = document.getElementById('variableb').value;
        var inputc = document.getElementById('variablec').value;
        
        root = Math.pow(inputb,2) - 4 * inputa * inputc;
        root1 = (-inputb + Math.sqrt(root))/2*inputa
        root2 = (-inputb + Math.sqrt(root))/2*inputa 
        
        document.getElementById('root1').value = root1;
        document.getElementById('root2').value = root2;
        if(root<'0')
        {
            alert('This equation has no real solution.')
        }
        else {
            if(root=='0')
            {
                document.getElementById('root1').value = root1
                document.getElementById('root2').value = 'No Second Answer'
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('root1').value = root1
                document.getElementById('root2').value = root1
                }
            }
    };
    document.getElementById('erase').onClick.document.getElementById('form1').reset();
}
</script>

<style>
#container
{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Quadratic Root Finder!</h1>
<form id="form1">
    a:<input id="variablea" value="" type="text">
    <br/>
    b:<input id="variableb" value="" type="text">
    <br />
    c:<input id="variablec" value="" type="text">
    <br />
    <input id="calculate" value="Calculate!" type="button">
    <input id="erase" value="Clear" type="button">
    <br />
    <br />
    Roots:
    <br />
    <input id="root1" type="text" readonly>
    <br />
    <input id="root2" type="text" readonly>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there an explainable reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a "ready" event like that. If you want to do things at what's commonly thought of as the "ready" point, you'll need to use a framework. Otherwise, you can use "onload" instead of "ready".

If, for example, you were using jQuery, you'd do this:

```
$(function() {
    var inputa = document.getElementById('variablea').value;
    var inputb = document.getElementById('variableb').value;
    var inputc = document.getElementById('variablec').value;
    // etc ...
});
```

Without that, you'd do:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // all your stuff
};
```

Also:

```
 ... .onclick.calculateQuad() {
```

makes no sense at all.

Comment: OK, I just tried that because the other method wasn't working but I figured out why, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong
`document.getElementById('calculate').onClick.calculateQuad()`
It must be
`document.getElementById('calculate').onClick = function ()`

And this is wrong too
`document.getElementById('erase').onClick.document.getElementById('form1').reset();`
Fixing:
`document.getElementById('erase').onClick = function(){document.getElementById('form1').reset();}`

Comment: I think you mean `.onclick= calculateQuad` (sets the function itself).  I don't think what you have will work.  Not 100% sure, but I am sure taht what I just put will work.  Part 2 seems right, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
.onClick.document.getElementById('form1').reset()
```

I think you want to turn this into:

```
.onclick = function () { document.getElementById('form1').reset(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use Jquery

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#variablea").click(function(element)
       {
         ///....operation
       });
});

you can use $(" input").click(function(element){})  operate all of input elements